# Find measure of angle in the triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

In a $ΔABC$, $D$ is midpoint of $BC$ such that $DA=DB=DC$, $BE$ and $CF$ are angle bisectors of $ABC$ and $ACB.EG$ and $FH$ are perpendicular to $BC$. Find measure of angle $HAG$

So I am a IX grader, and I have been stuck on this problem for about 40 mins and am not able to progress further. First I applied the angle bisector theorem
$$\frac{BC}{AB} = \frac{CE}{AE}\tag i$$

$$\frac{CB}{AC}=\frac{BF}{AF}\tag{ii}$$

From equations (i) and (ii) I obtained
$$\frac {CE.AB}{AE}=\frac {BF.AC}{AF}$$

I also obtained angle $BAC=90$ degrees from angle sum property however after that I am stuck, I tried constructing parallel lines to BC but no avail,
I thought to construct a circumcircle as $DA=DB=DC$ in hope to apply some properties but no progress yet.
Any thoughtful comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please use mathjax to have a better format for the mathematical objects. (Simply just enclose the formulas between dollar signs. There are some further fine tuning operations, but this should make a lot of the stuff more readable.) See also: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Note that the star, `*`, is a markup sign, it is "sensitive" first as a decoration of text. So `*some text*` typed in the message box makes that "some text" italic like this: *some text*. Please edit...

Comment: done, now is it fine?

Comment: HINT. Drop height $AK$. Note that triangle $AKC$ is similar to $ABC$ and $$AK:AC=AB:BC=AE:EC=KG:GC.$$

Comment: I presume $E,F$ are on the sides $AC,AB$ respectively rather than, e.g., on the circle diameter $BC$?

Comment: @user10354138 no BC is not the diameter I simply constructed a circumcircle

Comment: @NikhilPanigrahy $BC$ is the diameter.  That's why the midpoint of $BC$ is equidistant away from all three points $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]The angle is equal $45^°$. Use that CHFA and BGEA are inscribed in circles.

Comment: umm can you please elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @NikhilPanigrahy because "angle in a semicircle is a right angle", we have that CHFA is inscribed in a circle with CF as a diameter; BGEA is inscribed in a circle with BE as a diameter. And then, you can use a variety of angle-chasing methods to arrive at the answer. For example, you can use "angle in the same segment are equal" to find angle HFC = HAC = 67.5 degrees. Then use symmetry to conclude.

Comment: @BenjaminWang HFC is not necessary 67.5 degrees.

Comment: @user My bad. AD need not be perpendicular to CB.

Comment: @BenjaminWang In any case the answer can be much improved by adding the details.

Comment: Thanks mate understood it now